# How to unblock Hard Blocked wifi in ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: networking, wireless, 18.04, wifi-hardware-switch

My HP Laptop using Realtec network adapter is not able to connect to wifi.

As it shows `Airplane Mode On :- Use Hardware switch to turn off` I tried pressing it 100 times but no result.

Also I tried following many questions on forum but all were for Lenovo or Dell and older version of ubuntu still none of them worked.

My `rfkill list all` command shows :

```
0 : phy0 : Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
```

What I tried :

1. `rfkill unblock all`
2. Blacklisting hp-wmi.conf
3. Suspending laptop (some weird tutorial from youtube)

> P.S I have dual booted with windows 10 and wifi is working fine there

Answer (score 0):

The issue of HP wireless being inoperable because of a hard block and therefore the usual wireless key not toggling wireless on and off is long-standing. There are only a few things you can try.

First, try removing the helper module hp_wmi and then try to switch the wireless on with the key combination.

You could also try:

```
sudo modprobe -r hp_wmi
sudo rfkill unblock all
rfkill list all
```

Second, check the user guide for your HP laptop and be certain that the wireless key combination you are using is correct. Be certain that you are not using Fn+F12, for example, if the user guide says it is simply F12. On the other hand, if you are certain you are using the correct sequence, try the wrong sequence as an experiment; i.e., use Fn+F12 (or whatever your sequence is) if the user guide says it’s F12 and vice versa.

Next, you can remove the card, tape off pin 20 and re-insert it: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2150597

You can, if all these steps fail, file a bug report against the module hp_wmi: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/

Finally, in many, but not every case, a USB wireless will also be hard blocked for the same reasons. If you want to try one, be certain to try it within a return period.

I regret that there isn’t a better answer for HP laptops.

Comment: don't work till second step at all .....won't try the pin 20 method .....I will file bug report but I will take another generation to solve. So won't be able to use linux  :( . Any reason why specifically HP ?

Comment: I haven't any idea. As I said, I regret there isn't a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

Turn off Airplane mode in the Wi-Fi settings panel. It looks something like this... (*or, if you see an airplane icon in the top panel, click on it, and turn it off there*).

[image]