# Problem with adapter TP-Link wn722n chipset(Atheros AR9271)

Tags: networking, drivers, lubuntu, atheros

I cannot use adapter TP-Link wn722n on lubuntu 20.04 on laptop. I tried to install drivers for github but nothing works. Kernel version is 5.15.0-56. Please can you give me more information and suggestions what can i try to do, to fix this problem. Meanwhile i also cannot use wifi which is integrated on my laptop. Activation is on F12 button. When i activate it's still writes, wifi disabled. Also when i type sudo rfkill list, it shows that it's hard blocked. Also to mention,all these things (integrated wifi and adapter TP-link) works normally on windows OS.
Thanks in advance.

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/klC66.jpg-rfkill list all
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LTIjk.jpg-dmesg | grep arh9
I just can add like link cause of some missing points so... It can be open like that.

Also this adapter is in list bellow:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dqZby.jpg

Comment: Please edit your question to show the exact result of the terminal command: `rfkill list all` and: `sudo dmesg | grep ath9`

Comment: Probable duplicate: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1090270/how-to-unblock-hard-blocked-wifi-in-ubuntu-18-04/1090272#1090272

Comment: @chill555, do you maybe know, if there is some references or link for downloading drivers for TP-Link WN722n for kernel 5.15.0-56?

Comment: No. The required driver has been included in the kernel for many years. A newer or older or different driver isn't going to fix the hp_wmi and rfkill problem.

Comment: Ahaa, so there is not so much what i can do to fix this problem, instead of hp_wmi and rfkill? Is this problem related to HP, or?

Comment: All you can do it remove the card and tape off pin 20. It is an hp-wmi (HP) problem entirely. I regret that I have no better suggestion.

Comment: And about tp link adapter?

Comment: If the helper module hp_wmi reports that the airplane mode switch F12 is set to disable wireless, then *all* wireless is disabled.

Comment: hi @chili555, sry for not answering on the time, i can tell you that problem is solved thankfully to you. I remove the internal wifi card from my HP laptop, and after that I pluged in TP-Link adapter and wifi list are shown. I also tried to plug in Netis Wifi adapter and wifi list are also shown. So thank you for that advice. Best Regards chill555.